# Jira export via bash

Tags: backup, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I'm wondering whether it is possible to export data into XML via bash. Of course I could make a dump from database but XML is being choose by procedure of migration which I don't want to change. 
As far as I have noticed exporting via rest API is not possible.

Is it possible to do it another way? Plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do backup XML via bash via REST API. 
I was informed by Atlassian team that this is not possible. They are working on it but solution is not ready yet.
Only way of exporting data is by backup and restore from database.